# Show QListView in QMessageBox

Tags: qt, qlistview, qmessagebox

I'm completely new with QT and find it quite confusing.

I created a QListView (called "listview") and would like to show that in my QMessageBox:

```
const int resultInfo = QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Generate Software"),
    tr("The following files will be changed by the program:"),
    => Here the QListView should show up!
    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
if (resultInfo != QMessageBox::Yes) {
    return;
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QMessageBox` is designed to serve texts and buttons only. See [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#details).

If you just want to have a "More details" text, try using [detail text property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#detailedText-prop). In that case, you will have to create the message box using its constructor and set the icons, texts explicitly, not using the convenient `information()` function.

If you still want to have a list view in the message box, you should consider using `QDialog`, which is the base class of `QMessageBox`. Small example below:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDialog>
#include <QListView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog{this};
    dialog->setWindowTitle(tr("Fancy title"));

    auto button = new QPushButton{tr("OK"), this};
    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, dialog, &QDialog::accept);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout{dialog};
    layout->addWidget(new QLabel{tr("Description"), this});
    layout->addWidget(new QListView{this});
    layout->addWidget(button);

    dialog->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, will try that. Do you have any example code of a QDialog with a QListView in it?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, super helpful! One last question, how do I get my actual QListView (called "listview"), that contains the data, into it now?

Comment: You have to have a model to store the data (suggesting QStandardItemModel), then call `listview.setModel()`. Please consider marking the answer correct and upvote if your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what has been said before, it is easy  to add any widget to a QMessageBox. All you need to do is create your widget, say a QComboBox. Then create an instance of QMessageBox. Then get its layout which is a QGridLayout. Cast the QLayout value to QGridLayout and then you can add the widget thus:

```
QComboBox *myWidget = new QComboBox();
.. add items as necessary
QMessageBox* box = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Question, "Select value", "Select the value",QMessageBox::Ok);
QLayout *layout = box.layout();
((QGridLayout*)layout)->addWidget(myWidget, 1,2);
int ret = box.exec();
```

After returning from the QMessageBox. *myWidget* is set to the value that the user selected.